# Null Pointer Exception with multiple callables

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, thread-safety

I am getting Null Pointer Exception for the below code.

```
private class ProcessingThread implements Callable<List<Object>> {

        @Autowired
        private DataRetrievalService dataRetrievalService;
        String startDateTime;
        String endDateTime;
        int stationId;
        Set<String> channels;
        List<Integer> sensors;

        public ProcessingThread(String startDateTime, String endDateTime, int stationId, Set<String> channels,
                List<Integer> sensors) {
            super();
            this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
            this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
            this.stationId = stationId;
            this.channels = channels;
            this.sensors = sensors;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Object> call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("I was called!!");
            return dataRetrievalService.getTimeSeriesData(stationId, channels, sensors, startDateTime, endDateTime);
        }
    }
```

**Caller method :-**

```
int noOfYears=1;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfYears; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                endDateTime = dateTimeUtil.getOneYearLaterDate(startDateTime);
            else {
                startDateTime = dateTimeUtil.getOneYearLaterDate(startDateTime);
                endDateTime = dateTimeUtil.getOneYearLaterDate(endDateTime);
            }
            Callable<List<Object>> callable = new ProcessingThread(startDateTime, endDateTime, stationId, channels,
                    sensors);
            futures.add(executorService.submit(callable));
        }
        executorService.awaitTermination(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (Future<List<Object>> future : futures) {
            int i = 0;
            if (i == 0)
                b = new ArrayList<>(future.get());
            else
                b.add(future.get());
            i++;
        }
}
```

Calling this always gives the Null Pointer Exception after 300 Seconds the future itself is becoming null. Although if i do a normal execution the code works fine! Can anyone please explain me where am i doing wrong!

Calling the below code everything works fine!

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfYears; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                endDateTime = dateTimeUtil.getOneYearLaterDate(startDateTime);
            else {
                startDateTime = dateTimeUtil.getOneYearLaterDate(startDateTime);
                endDateTime = dateTimeUtil.getOneYearLaterDate(endDateTime);
            }
            futures.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<List<Object>>() {

                @Override
                public List<Object> call() throws Exception {
                    return dataRetrievalService.getTimeSeriesData(stationId, channels, sensors, "2010-04-11 12:23:00.0", "2011-04-11 12:23:00.0");
                }
            }));

        }
        executorService.awaitTermination(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int i = 0;
        for (Future<List<Object>> future : futures) {
            if (i == 0)
                b = new ArrayList<>(future.get());
            else
                b.add(future.get());
            i++;
        }
```

As here the startDateTime and endDateTime has to be declared final or effective i can not use this code and this 2 are variables for me and will change for every iteration in for loop.

Comment: I can't be sure without the crash log but it seems that you maybe forgot to initialize `ProcessingThread.dataRetrievalService`?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly - like giving the exception stack trace.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of responsiveness.

Comment: @GhostCat : I am responding to the question even updating it to make it more clear.

Comment: There is still no stack trace. That is essential to understand *where* exactly the problem occurs!

Comment: @GhostCat: I will put the stacktrace but it will be on help. As the reason is that the ExecutorService is getting timedout and the futures is null.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `int i = 0;` to outside the loop.

You keep recreating it with value = 0, the `b` arraylist contains only one final value after loop.

You also have dependency issue, you should mark your `ProcessingThread` as a bean (make it public and annotate it with `@Component` or `@Service`

```
@Component
public class ProcessingThread implements...
```

Without it, your `DataRetrievalService dataRetrievalService` is `null`, hence NPE is thrown.